# Discrete math logic, when is a proof finished?

Tags: logic, discrete-mathematics

So what I did in this problem is:

[image]

3. p →(¬r∨ ¬p)   (1,2, hypothetical syllogism)
4. p              (assumption for proof by division into cases)
5. (¬r∨ ¬p)       (3,4, modus ponens)
6. (¬r∨ ¬p)       (3-5 and proof by division into cases).

At this point, in my eyes, the proof is finished. I have proven that the conclussion (¬r∨ ¬p) is true. But then I look in the hindsight, and I see that my teacher continues. On line 6 he instead assumes ¬p, and then from that he again writes (¬r∨ ¬p) on line 7. And now he concludes the proof (8.¬r∨ ¬p, 3-7, and proof by division into cases). Why didn't he stop at line 6 like I did and instead continued by assuming ¬p? Am I wrong or is my proof complete?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I might know the answer. When working with division into cases, you must always try to prove that the opposite of what you assume also works. In this case, on line 4, I assume p. Therefore I must also see what happens if I assume ¬p. Is this correct?

Comment: Correct. Happily, in your case, assuming "not p" immediately gives your result "not r or not p".